# How can I checkout the wxPython sources?

Tags: wxpython

While I was able to find a [wxPython source browser](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser) I was not able to find any checkout option for the source code.

Note, I tried `svn co http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wxPython/branches/WX_2_8_BRANCH` but it requiest an account, something I do not have.

Comment: Hi, does this mean that all wxpython sources are open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some info [here](http://www.wxwidgets.org/develop/svn.htm).
For anonymous (read-only) access, you can checkout wxWidgets from SVN with the following command:

```
svn checkout http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk wxWidgets
```

For example, to checkout the WX_2_8_BRANCH, use the following command:

```
svn checkout http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/branches/WX_2_8_BRANCH wxWidgets-2.8
```